# LINEST function in Microsoft excel; curve fitting tri-quadratic equation

Tags: excel, regression

Im trying to curve fit the first graph in the set of four using LINEST. This curve needs to be a graph of 3, possible 4, variables: Suction Pressure (SP), OD Temp, ID WB Temp, and possible ID DB Temp (other graphs didnt need the DB to work, may not be needed here). Isnt a simple LINEST, but a tri- or quad-quadratic LINEST.

Attempted: 2nd, 3rd degree LINEST fits using corresponding x,y values from first graph.

How do i do this?

[image]

Comment: I think the question needs additional clarification.  I'm not sure what you mean by 55 X value and 87/57 Y value.  Is this just an image chart you have or do you have all the points in a file?  Do you need curve fitting or interpolating between points.

Comment: curve fitting, the 55 and 58/57 for example is just the curve i want to fit. i just cant figure out how to get that first polynomial graph (or any of the subsequent ones)

Comment: more specifically, for the first curve, cross sections go up in increments of 10 so x:{55,65,...115} and the Y values are easily read from this..

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you have the data in table format you can use the following formula

```
=LINEST(knownys, knownxs^{1, 2, 3})
```

When you enter it select 4 cells across, put in the formula and enter with **ctrl+shift+enter**.  The values it returns would be A1,A2,A3, and b going left to right if the formula has the following equation: y=A1*x^3+A2*x^2+A3*x+B.

Another option is to fit curves using the chart trendline and you can get the exponents from there.

[Source](http://people.stfx.ca/bliengme/ExcelTips/Polynomial.htm)

**Edit**

Based on your edits I would suggest you find a better statistical software then excel but
one option would be to use solver.  You would set up a bunch of cells with the constants you wanted a1,a2,b1,b2 etc.

Then you would have your columns with your independent variables (OD temp, ID WB Temp, etc) a column with your known ys, a column with your calculated ys and an error column (known y - calcy)^2 you would sum up the error column and run solver to minimize the sum of the error.

calc y would be something like `=a1*ODtemp^2+a2*ODtemp+b1*WBtemp^2+b2*WBtemp+C` or whatever form your formula needs to fit.

Comment: the graphs need to be a function of OD temp, ID WB Temp, and suction pressure. Possibly even ID DB temp. 4 variables...quad-quadtratic equation fitting

Comment: I don't think you will find an excel function to do that and you would probably be better off using some sort of statistical software although you may be able to get close using something like solver (see my edit above)

Comment: do you think I should go with something like maple or matlab then? I successfully got graphs using bi-quadratic with LINEST as seen in : 

For two variables I have 6 columns; Outdoor Air Temp, Wetbulb Temp, and Superheat given in the form of:
OAT, OAT^2, WB, WB^2, OD*WB, SH.
I use LINEST(SH1:SH13,OAT:1:OD*WB:13,,TRUE) and I come out with a VERY accurate representation of the curve..